# XPATH expression not respected with filter using variable

Tags: xpath

There is this XSLT code in one of my projects

```
<xsl:template match="strategic-objectives/list/item" mode="table-of-contents">    
  <div class="toc">
    <h3 class="report">Strategic objective: <a href="#sf_{flex_value}"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a></h3>

    <xsl:variable name="flex_value" select="flex_value"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//root/data/operational-outcomes/list/item[sf = $flex_value]" mode="table-of-contents"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

how much ever I try, the data for `<operational-outcomes>` does not match to `sf = flex_value`, but `sf = '020000'` matches.

I have checked the `<flex_value>` if proper in XML for the `<strategic-objectives>` item. It in fact also has `020000` as one of the values.

### data

```
<data xsql-timing="3131">
  <time>20 of April, 2014 (14:22)    </time> 

  <strategic-objectives>
    <list type="strategic_objective" xsql-timing="81">

      <item num="1">
        <context>PB08V6    </context> 
        <flex_value_set_name>ILO_AFF_SF    </flex_value_set_name> 
        <attribute5>10    </attribute5> 
        <flex_value>010000    </flex_value> 
        <hierarchy_level>1    </hierarchy_level> 
        <title>Policy Making    </title> 
      </item>

      <item num="4">
        <context>PB08V6    </context> 
        <flex_value_set_name>ILO_AFF_SF    </flex_value_set_name> 
        <attribute5>10    </attribute5> 
        <flex_value>200000    </flex_value> 
        <hierarchy_level>1    </hierarchy_level> 
        <title>Employment    </title> 
        <description>  </description> 
        <text> </text> 
      </item>

    </list>
  </strategic-objectives>

  <operational-outcomes>
    <list type="outcome" xsql-timing="477">

      <item num="9">
        <context>PB08V6    </context> 
        <flex_value_set_name>ILO_AFF_SF    </flex_value_set_name> 
        <flex_value>220025    </flex_value> 
        <parent_flex_value>220000    </parent_flex_value> 
        <hierarchy_level>3    </hierarchy_level> 
        <status>10    </status> 
        <attribute5>40    </attribute5> 
        <title>REVISED - Policies for growth, employment and poverty reduction    </title> 
        <description></description> 
        <text> </text> 
        <sf>200000    </sf> 
      </item>

      <item num="10">
        <context>PB08V6    </context> 
        <flex_value_set_name>ILO_AFF_SF    </flex_value_set_name> 
        <flex_value>740050    </flex_value> 
        <parent_flex_value>740000    </parent_flex_value> 
        <hierarchy_level>3    </hierarchy_level> 
        <status>10    </status> 
        <attribute5>40    </attribute5> 
        <title>DELETED - Internal Administration and Security    </title> 
        <sf>700000    </sf> 
      </item>
    </list>
  </operational-outcomes>

</data>
```

Comment: Make absolutely sure that `<flex_value>` contains exactly the same value as `<sf>`. This also means whitespace like line-breaks. Also, you don't need a variable, just use `current()/flex_value`.

Comment: Showing your XML would also be a good idea.

Comment: This is part of the xml

Comment: I would second @Tomalaks's suggestion. Looking at your sample input XML it's obvious that you have *at least* trailing white space. One way to get rid of this is to use the standard XSLT function `normalize-space` before comparing strings.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your XML source, there's a white-space problem:

```
<flex_value>200000    </flex_value>
```

Every character matters, `200000␣␣␣␣` is not the same as `200000`.

`normalize-whitespace()` strips leading and trailing whitespace, and collapses multiple subsequent whitespace characters within a string into one. Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="flex_value" select="normalize-space(flex_value)"/>
```

`␣␣foo␣␣␣bar␣␣` becomes `foo␣bar`.

Comment: it's just `normalize-space()`